# How do I store a custom details that contain a value, in a new column for mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

My goal is to set certain dealers/users whether they can get commission or not when doing transactions. I created a column `comm_enabled` boolean value in my table called `dealers`. Now, I need to find a way to store a `custom user details` that contains `DealerId` (since I just need to allow only certain dealers to not get commission), `isCommEnabled` field in the principal for the security context. So when login, it will already save the settings whether the dealer should be charged commission or not. As to where it sets the `custom user details`, it is done at this file:

DealerUserService.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DealerUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final DealerMapper dealerMapper;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        DealerDTO dealerDTO = Optional.ofNullable(dealerMapper.retrieveByUsername(username))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found for " + username));
        DealerUser dealerUser = new DealerUser();
        dealerUser.setUsername(dealerDTO.getUserName());
        dealerUser.setPassword(dealerDTO.getPassword());
        dealerUser.setRoles(Collections.singletonList(DealerRole.DEALER.name()));
        dealerUser.setDealerId(dealerDTO.getId());
        dealerUser.setCommEnabled(dealerDTO.isCommEnabled());
        return dealerUser;
    }
}
```

My `dealers` table now have the following columns:

- id
- username
- firstname
- lastname
- password
- status
- phonenumber
- lastlogin
- createddt
- changeddt
- email
- comm_enabled (newly created column that is still null)